# Почему при запуске программы WebStorm она запускается свернуто?

Tags: webstorm

Почему при запуске программы WebStorm она запускается свернуто? Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы программа всегда при запуске открывалась в развернутом виде? Может какие-то настройки есть? Уже смотрел, но ничего подходящего в настройках не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebStorm-а под рукой нет, но никакой разницы, потому что "ничего подходящего в настройках не нашел" тут ни при чем.
На ярлыке запуска программы в Start Menu жмем "open file location" и находим ярлык запуска. Если ярлык уже на рабочем столе, то пропускаем первый шаг. На ярлыке правой кнопкой, затем "Свойства", а затем выставляем так, как показано на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]